# Maui/Forms : Is there a way to get this desired effect like the wells fargo app' currency field

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

Basically, using a Entry in Maui/Forms, as I type, the fields should get filled from right to left. I tried setting the FlowDirection, TextChanged event handler but nothing seems to work. Not sure how they are doing it. I see something like this in the javascript, but that seems to be jquery related. Any ideas?
[image]

Video
https://imgur.com/a/v1XVsWp

Comment: No, I should have attached a video. Attaching it. It did not help.

Comment: Ah, that would require you to build a custom Behavior or control.

Comment: I updated my answer with a behavior you can add to an entry to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**New answer**

Given the video, here is a behavior which will give you the desired effect:

```
public class CurrencyEntryBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
{
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged += Entry_TextChanged;

        base.OnAttachedTo(entry);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged -= Entry_TextChanged;

        base.OnDetachingFrom(entry);
    }

    private void Entry_TextChanged(object? sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is not Entry entry || string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue))
            return;

        // Remove any non-numeric characters from the text
        var newText = new string(e.NewTextValue.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());

        // Convert the numeric text to a decimal value
        if (decimal.TryParse(newText, out var amount) && amount > 0)
        {
            // Format the decimal amount to the desired currency format
            string formattedAmount = $"{amount / 100:C}";

            // Set the formatted text to the Entry
            entry.Text = formattedAmount;
        }
        else
        {
            // If parsing fails, reset the Entry text
            entry.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        // Move the cursor to the end of the text
        entry.CursorPosition = entry.Text.Length;
    }
}
```

And here is some xaml showing how to use it:

```
<Entry
    HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
    Keyboard="Numeric"
    Placeholder="$0.00">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <local:CurrencyEntryBehavior />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

One thing to improve upon is to store the formattedAmount text in a field so you can compare against it when Entry_TextChanged is called again, as it will be called again when the behavior assigns formattedAmount to entry.Text.

---

**Old answer**

You can use:

```
HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
```

or:

```
HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
```

... depending on your preference. Text will get filled from right to left.